# Jenkins pipeline - Upon error go to postFailure block

Tags: bash, jenkins-pipeline

Folks,
I have the below Jenkins pipeline. I want to run all the stages, hence I got **catchError(buildResult: 'SUCCESS', stageResult: 'FAILURE')** in place.
I have a script **minion_notification.sh** which produces file called **"jk_buildpass.txt"**. Now, I want my build to got to postFailure block whenever condition **if [ ! -s jk_buildpass.txt ]** is matched. With **exit 1** the job is not failing and the consequent stages are getting executed. Any idea?

```html
pipeline = {
      ansiColor('xterm') {
      FILEVERSION = params.FILEVERSION.trim()
      def remote = [:]
      remote.name = 'xxx'
      remote.host = '10.xxx.xx.x'
      remote.allowAnyHosts = true
            withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'saltmaster', passwordVariable: 'password', usernameVariable: 'ops')]) {
            remote.user = 'ops'
            remote.password = password 
            stage (' Backup') {
              catchError(buildResult: 'SUCCESS', stageResult: 'FAILURE') {        
              sh './minion_notification.sh "${FILEVERSION}" "Validate" "backupdb"'
              sh(returnStdout: true, script: '''#!/bin/bash
                           if [ ! -s jk_buildpass.txt ];then
                            exit 1
                            else
                            echo "jk_buildpass is not empty"
                            fi
                        '''.stripIndent()) 
                 
               }   
            }
            stage (' Uninstall') {
              catchError(buildResult: 'SUCCESS', stageResult: 'FAILURE') {         
              sh './minion_notification.sh "${FILEVERSION}" "Validate" "IRMUninstall"'
              sh(returnStdout: true, script: '''#!/bin/bash
                           if [ ! -s jk_buildpass.txt ];then
                           exit 1
                            else
                            echo "jk_buildpass is not empty"
                            fi
                        '''.stripIndent())   
                 
               }   
            }
            
            stage('Run DDMU') {

                 sh './minion_notification.sh "${FILEVERSION}" "jenkins-display"'
            }
            
        }     
         // sh './slk_notify.sh "Upgrade successfully completed for -   ${FILEVERSION} " "*********** " "good" ":jenkins:"
      } 
  } 
postFailure = {
      sh './slk_notify.sh " Upgarde failed for -  ${FILEVERSION} " "danger" ":jenkinserror:"'
}

postAlways = {
    echo 'Cleaning Workspace now'
    env.WORKSPACE = pwd()
    //sh "rm ${env.WORKSPACE}/* -fr"
}

node{
     properties([
     parameters([
            string(name: 'FILEVERSION', defaultValue: '', description: 'Enter the file name to be process ')
             ])
      ]) 
    try {
        pipeline()
    } catch (e) {
        postFailure()
        throw e
    } finally {
        postAlways()
    }
}
```